# Algorithm for moving links with priority to head of a list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, queue, priority-queue

I have to create a priority queue using a linked list, BUT I KEEP GETTING A SEGMENTATION FAULT. I first generate a queue with no priority (priority=0). My algorithm is as such for enqueueing:

```
1. Create a new Link, pointer for second link, and pointer for swap
2. If queue is empty, set new Link = front & back
3. If not, check if new Link has any priority, if priority = 0, move new link 
to the back of`queue
4. If new link has any priority, move it to the front
5. Check to see if the front is less than
6. if 2nd link has no priority or if 1st link has less priority, perform no swap
7. if 2nd link's priority is <= front link; swap
```

in main I generate a 5 link queue with no priority, then I enqueue a link with no priority outside of the loop to ensure I have a solid algorithm. I enqueue another a link with actual priority, etc. (you can see what i did in main)

> **main.cpp**

```
//System Libraries
#include "PriorityQueue.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//Creating a new queue 
    PriorityQueue queue;
    int MAX_VALUES = 5, num;

    //Enqueueing each link one by one and displaying queue alongside
    cout<<"\n"<<MAX_VALUES<< " values enqueued";
    for(int x = 0; x < MAX_VALUES; x++){
        cout<<"\nEnqueueing..."<<x<<": ";
        queue.enqueue(x, 0);
        queue.printQueue();
    }

    //displaying results of enqueueing with priority
    cout<<"\n------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enqueueing links with priority"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEnqueueing w/ lvl. 1 priority...10: ";
    queue.enqueue(10, 0); //newcomer with top priority
    queue.printQueue(); 
    cout<<"\nEnqueueing w/ lvl. 2 priority... 9: ";
    queue.enqueue(9, 2); //newcomer with lower priority than front
    queue.printQueue();
            cout<<"\nDequeueing..."<<queue.returnFront()<<": "; //first two in queue get dequeued first
            queue.dequeue(num);
            queue.printQueue();
            cout<<"\nDequeueing..."<<queue.returnFront()<<": ";
            queue.dequeue(num);
            queue.printQueue();
    cout<<"\nEnqueueing w/ lvl. 1 priority...11: ";
    queue.enqueue(11, 1); //newcomer to queue with same as top priority
    queue.printQueue();

    //Dequeueing each link one by one and displaying it alongside
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        cout<<"\nDequeueing..."<<queue.returnFront()<<": ";
        queue.dequeue(num);
        queue.printQueue();
    }

    //Attempting one more dequeue to display isEmpty message
    cout<<"\nDequeueing...";
    queue.dequeue(num);

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> **PriorityQueue.cpp**

//Preprocessor Directives

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUE_H
#define PRIORITYQUEUE_H

//System Libraries
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PriorityQueue{
private: struct Link{
            int data;
            int priority;
            Link *next;
         };
         Link *front, *back;
         int listLength; 
public: PriorityQueue(){front = nullptr; back = nullptr;};
        ~PriorityQueue(){destroyList();};
        int returnFront();
        void printQueue();
        void destroyList();
        void enqueue(int, int);
        void dequeue(int &);
        bool isEmpty() const;
};

void PriorityQueue::destroyList(){
    int value; // Dummy variable for dequeue

    while(!isEmpty())
        dequeue(value);
}

void PriorityQueue::enqueue(int val, int priority){
    Link *newLink = new Link;//pointer for new link
    Link *linkPtr = nullptr; //pointer for second link
    Link *temp = nullptr;    //pointer for swap of links

    //allocating new link to pointer and storing number
    newLink->data = val;
    newLink->next = nullptr;
    newLink->priority = priority;

    //If stack is empty, make the new link the top of stack
    if(isEmpty()){
        front = newLink;
        back = newLink;
    }
    else{
        /* 1. move newLink to the front, if priority exists
         * 2. make newLink point to the front
         * 3. make the newLink the new front of the list
         * 4. if 2nd link has no priority or if 1st link has 
         *    less priority,perform no swap
         * 5. if 2nd link's priority is <= front link; swap
         */
        if(newLink->priority == 0){
        back->next = newLink;
        back = newLink;
        }
        else if(newLink->priority >= 1){
            newLink->next= front;        //1.
            linkPtr = newLink->next;     //2.
            front = newLink;             //3.

            if(front->priority < linkPtr->priority ||linkPtr->priority == 0){} //4.
            else if(front->priority >= linkPtr->priority){ //5.
                temp->data = linkPtr->data;
                temp->priority = linkPtr->priority;

                linkPtr->data = front->data;
                linkPtr->priority = front->priority;

                front->data = temp->data;
                front->priority = temp-> priority;
            }
        } 
    }

    //track list length
    listLength++; 
}

//removing links from front
void PriorityQueue::dequeue(int& topVal){
     Link *temp = nullptr;

    //If Queue is empty, message is displayed after dequeue attempt
    if(isEmpty()){
        cout<<"Queue is empty."<<endl;
    }
    else{
        //save the top value into num
        topVal = front->data;

        //delete the front node 
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete temp;

        //update list length
        listLength--;
    }
}

//returns whether the list is empty or not
bool PriorityQueue::isEmpty() const{
    bool status;

    if(listLength > 0)
        status = false;
    else
        status = true;

    return status;     
}

//returns the value at the top of the queue
int PriorityQueue::returnFront(){
    return front->data;
}

//Displays all values in queue
void PriorityQueue::printQueue(){
    Link *newLink = front;

    while(newLink != nullptr){
        cout<<"  "<<newLink->data;
        newLink = newLink->next;
    }
}

#endif /* PRIORITYQUEUE_H */
```

Comment: In step 2 in your list, there is really no "moving", instead you *add* the new node at the end or at the beginning of the list.

Comment: As for your question, what *is* your question? Do you have problems with the code you show? Do you just want a [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) of working code? If you haven't done it yet, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No it's not working, I forgot to mention I get a segmentation fault with my algorithm

Answer (score 0):

In the `PriotityQueue::enqueue` function, you have declared `temp=nullptr`.
So when you try to swap the two links using `temp->data` and `temp->priority`, you will get a segmentation fault.

The swapping can be done without `temp`.

```
void PriorityQueue::enqueue(int val, int priority){
...
else if(front->priority >= linkPtr->priority){ //5.
            front->next=linkPtr.next;
            linkPtr->next=front;
            front=linkPtr;
}
...
}
```

Comment: I've found a better way of doing this where instead of swapping links i just insert it where i need it lol